# Mouse is slow when SD card reader is in use

Tags: mouse, sd-card

I have a custom built desktop PC, that has a card reader. Whenever I put an SD card in it, the mouse is slow and not smooth anymore.

A little bit like mice use to feel when their ball was dirty (sorry if you are under 25, you may be too young to remember these goold old days).

It seems to be worse when there's a file transfer with the card, but even when it's not the case, the mouse slows down.

I suppose that an Intel i7 should be able to handle a mouse correctly, so there may be a problem somewhere.

I use Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

I had problems with my Ubuntu 18.04 slowing down on several occasions ever since I installed it. However some weeks ago I discovered "Solution 3" of [this It's FOSS article](https://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/)

Ever since I changed one line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` my system runs perfectly smooth.

Old line:

```
hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] dns myhostname
```

New line:

```
hosts:          files dns
```

Today I dumped an SD card on my laptop. Without this change reading the SD card took much longer and Ubuntu became very unresponsive during the process.

Before the change:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=sdcard.img status=progress
15929001984 bytes (16 GB, 15 GiB) copied, 2580 s, 6,2 MB/s  
31116288+0 records in
31116288+0 records out
15931539456 bytes (16 GB, 15 GiB) copied, 2580,5 s, 6,2 MB/s
```

After the change:

```
$ sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=sdcard.img status=progress
15927067136 bytes (16 GB, 15 GiB) copied, 869 s, 18,3 MB/s 
31116288+0 records in
31116288+0 records out
15931539456 bytes (16 GB, 15 GiB) copied, 869,426 s, 18,3 MB/s
```

I'm curious if this will help you as well and would be thankful if someone could explain this very strange observation of mine.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! This is a perfectly fine answer and you don't need to change anything, but since you're new here, I just want to suggest that if you want an explanation of how this fix works (I would give you one if I knew!), you should ask a new question about it, because this site isn't like a forum and the only way to reply to an answer is to comment on it, and comments are rather limited in many ways, and it's also more likely that you will get the information you want if you ask a question.